# Unable to submit voice file - PHP & Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to submit a voice file in my application by posting from my application form to my API. Checking the data from my code, i see that all data is submitted except my file.  However, i am not able to tell why the file only wouldn't get submitted. I included `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in my code to get the fix but that wouldn't work.

Any idea as to why my file isn't being posted but returned **false** ?

**API**

```
           public function API()
           { 
           $codeAPI = $request->get('key');
            if (empty($codeAPI)) {
            return response()->json([
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'code is not specified',
                    'receipient' => $recipients,                    
                    'file' => $request->hasFile('file');            
            ]);
            }
```

**Controller**

```
public function testAPI()
{
    $endPoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/';
    $codeKey= '';
    $url = $endPoint . '?key=' . $apiKey;
    $curlFile = $request->get('file');

        $data = [
           'recipient' => ['9901231001', '1239131001'],
           'content' => 'Learning API'
           'file' => $curlFile,
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($data));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
        return $result;
        curl_close($ch);
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <form class="form" method="POST" action="/test/api" >
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
  <div class="form-body">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="eventRegInput2">File</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="placeholder">
  </div>                               
  <div class="form-actions right">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary square btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1" >Submit</button>
 </button>
 </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

**Results**

```
   {"status":"error","message":"code key is not 
    specified","receipient":["9901231001","1239131001"],
"content":{Learning API},"file":false}
```

Comment: are you including the csrf token or field?

Comment: @T.Altena Yes. Please check the update with the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$request->file('file')` instead of `$request->get('file')` for get a file input. and make sure you add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form.

```
   public function testAPI()
    {
        $endPoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/';
        $codeKey= '';
        $url = $endPoint . '?key=' . $apiKey;
        $curlFile = $request->file('file');

            $data = [
               'recipient' => ['9901231001', '1239131001'],
               'content' => 'Learning API'
               'file' => $curlFile,
            ];

            $ch = curl_init();
            $headers = array();
            $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($data));
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            $result = json_decode($result, TRUE);
            return $result;
            curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Comment: When i add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` i returns `null` even before getting to the API. When i remove `enctype='multipart/form-data'`, i am able to get the file but then returns null after returning from the API